# Why would I set another branch besides master to track origin/master in Git?

Tags: git

This might be a dumb question, but I've been learning Git on [learngitbranching.js.org](https://learngitbranching.js.org/) and a lesson came up where they were talking about if it's possible to set another branch that's not master to track origin/master. As in:

> You can make any arbitrary branch track `o/master`, and if you do so,
>   that branch will have the same implied push destination and merge
>   target as `master`. This means you can run git push on a branch named
>   `totallyNotMaster` and have your work pushed to the `master` branch on
>   the remote!

I just don't understand why I would do that? Is there any scenario where this would be practical/needed? Do you guys ever do this in your work?

Comment: I would to it if I want to move my local master branch separately from origin's. Say... something twisted like you want to fork mariadb and create josefadb.... and have it as a completely separate project. Then you would like your master to move freely without being tied to mariadb's master branch.... but you might still want to track mariadb's master... then you could set up something like mariadb-master to track it... ultimately why would you do it? Because you can!!!! :-D

Comment: josefadb? You heretic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not done it  myself, so I am afraid that your Q is primarily-opinion based. One way to find out!

I think they are trying to prove the concept, that `local master` is just a branch like any other branch - but just called *master*. No additional privileges whatsoever for `local master` over other local branches. So, it just a branch and can be called `master`, `slave`, `banana`, anything, and can track `remote branches` such as: `master` or other branches that are named different.

The only *special* about the word `master` being used, is the convention where `remote default` branch is always called `master`, and no one can delete the `remote default` branch. So, you can delete `remote master` only when you pick another `remote branch` and set it as the default.

At the end of the day, not everything the you can do, will end up by you actually doing it.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much, makes more sense now!

Comment: @hemoglobin Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you have several remotes, then your "master" can't track "master" on both, so that is a clear case. Whether you even have local "master" in such a case might depend. It might be most clear to have "master1" tracking "origin/master" and "master2" tracking "secondremote/master" for example, to avoid any confusion about what local "master" would mean.

Also, more generally, having a branch names "master" is just a convention. Sometimes people want to make their lives... let's say, interesting, and set things up in unconventional ways.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not that match exactly with your question but it provide some details why developer create multiple branch and sub branch.

Git's grate developers providing the features through which we create multiple branch relate with single project as per our need to place separation of our code more accuracy towards branch deployment(It provide relief when you working on big scale project),

Normally there is some common flow which usually followed by most of the application which help to make your code fluent (Just example for provide more under stability),

**1. Master:** which contains latest stable code of your site which can deploy on your actual server and share those with your recent user. Errors or bugs in this beach create bad impact on your customer  and also possible to loss oft valuable customer at this stage.

**2. Deploy:** This branch comes just before master which contains latest features or fixing which done recently by developer. This branch basically for company authorise people which gives you project and they check work in based on requirements or not. Or also used by beta testers. If any changes or bug found in this time directly set on bug-fix branch and reallocated to appropriate developer. UI testing ,checking and validation testing or cross verified over here.

**3. Development:** All the teams worked on projects are having sub branch inside this branch and they take latest pull for getting change for another team which worked on same module or push them for testing. Testing team test it from all scenario and push that change in deploy when whole task complete

**4 Team Branch:** In current world micro-services are more popular and powerful scenario and based on their working criteria multiple team worked on that project which define by their module. And that team only handle work of that module like auth service,  report service, etc.

**5.Task Branch:** Any request for change comes to the team they create the sub branch from team branch and do their work inside this. Also they differentiate their work based on feature, modify or bug-fix.

So basically graph create like this,

> Master > Deploy > Development > Team > Task

All the level pull push process do vital role. Be careful to do that.

If git is not there

Comment: First of all this is not what OP asked for. 2nd - the scheme that you outlined is stupendously overcomplicated. This is the first time I hear about such weird scheme, why do you think that Git developers have anything to do with it?